# Changing values of string variable with an if clause in SPSS

Tags: spss

I have a dataset that looks like the one below. I will need to use both ID1 and ID2 to identify each row. The responses in the OpenText vary greatly.

```
+-------+--------+-------------+
|  ID1  |  ID2   | OpenText    |
+=======+========+=============+
| AAAA  |  01    | Morning(!)  |
+-------+--------+-------------+
| AAAA  |  02    | Red Shoe    |
+-------+--------+-------------+
| AAbb  |  01    | Curtain     |
+-------+--------+-------------+
```

My aim is to change some of the values of the OpenText depending on the value in both of the ID variables. I am not sure what is the type of the variables: in the variable view, they are all nominal.
The code I have written but doesn't work is the following:

```
IF (ID1 = AAAA) AND (ID2 = 01) OpenText = "NIGHT".
EXECUTE.
```

I have also tried to do this with 'select if'

```
SELECT IF (ID1 = AAAA) AND (ID2 = 01).
COMPUTE OpenText = replace(OpenText, 'NIGHT').
EXECUTE.
```

None of them works. I get an error about incorrect variable name (either the name is more than 64 characters, or it is not defined by a previous command.)
Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that ID1 and ID2 are also string variables, and then you must surround the data entries with semicolon:

```
IF (ID1 = "AAAA") AND (ID2 = "01") OpenText = "NIGHT".
```

This should work.

Comment: Correct! the one id was not string it can be turned to a string like this  `ALTER TYPE ID2(F0).` and then it works like a charm